# Then the sum of the entries of A equals ___________?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $R^3$(column vectors) with the standard inner product. Let L be the one
dimensional subspace of $R^3$
spanned by the column vector $(2, 1, 2)^t$
.Let A be the $3 × 3$ matrix such that the linear transformation of $R^ 3$ given by $x → Ax$ is orthogonal projection onto the line L. Then the sum of the entries of A equals ___________$?$

My attempts :  i take  $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

now  $ Ax$ =$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.$(2,1,2)^t$

IS its  corrects ?????

the sum of the entries of A equals $2+1+2 =5$

Comment: The sum of all entries of your matrix $A$ is $3$, not $5$; and $A$ is **not** the orthogonal projection onto the line $L$.

Comment: ? where is the dependency on $x$ in what you wrote for $Ax$?

Comment: im not getting @JoséCarlosSantos......that  mean  i have  to take   nilpotent matrix ?  is it correct?

Comment: it means you have to consider the matrix A of the projection on the line L, not the identity matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orthogonal projection matrix on the line described by the vector $v$ is $P=\dfrac{1}{\Vert v\Vert^2}  vv^T$.

Comment: In your case $\Vert v \Vert$  (length of vector $v$) is equal to $3$.

Comment: and $vv^T=[ 2 \  \ 1 \ \ 2]^T[2 \ \ 1 \  \ 2]$

Comment: i got$ P= \begin{bmatrix} \ 4&2&4\\2&1&2\\4&2&4\end{bmatrix}.\frac{1}{9}$.....is  it correct @Widawensen

Comment: @Stupid I think it is correct...

Comment: then  mean  sum of entries  of $A =  1/9( 2(4+2+4) +2+1+2) = 1/9(20+5) =   \frac {25}{9}$  ...now  is its correct ??@widawensen

Comment: Note also  that in this formula  vector $v /  \Vert v \Vert$ is normalized to unit length. You can also check that $P^2=P$ what is characteristic for projection matrices

Comment: Yes... $5^2/3^2$

Comment: thanks  a lots @widawensen